# Is there an easy way to standardize quadratic irrationals formatting?

Tags: output-formatting

**FromContinuedFraction** returns quadratic irrationals when the continued fraction is periodic. Examples:

In:=**FromContinuedFraction[{0, 3, {2, 6}}]**

Out:=1/(2 Sqrt[3])

In:=**FromContinuedFraction[{0, 2, {5, 10}}]**

Out:=1/6 (1 + Sqrt[3])

I'd like the general form of a quadratic irrational to be (P - Sqrt[D])/Q or (P + Sqrt[D])/Q, but Mathematica's output is unpredictable, sometimes with radicals in the denominator. The output may also be just an integer or a rational number. By looking at the FullForm of the various results, I see that there may be a dozen or more different formats, taking into account the signs of the parts. I've created a clunky routine that tries to treat each formatting case separately. Is there a direct way to get these diverse outputs into a standard format?